# Drupal DB : Have to move some data from one table to another by cheking the condition at remote server..!

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, cck, remote-server

I am working with a portal, where there is content type. The front end developer who made this portal added a CCK field for file attachment & there is already File attachment field given by core.
Now we won't go to discuss why did he do that as I also don't know.

Now I have to removed that CCK field & if I remove directly, I will loose all the data uploaded by this field as it will remove the table of it.

So now I am trying to replace the value from this CCK field table to default upload table & update the filepath in files table..so that it would come in view for attached files.

Because I am not very good at PHP or MySQL I am seeking some help from you guys..

Here is the basic code, which I have written...please suggest the correction & please tell me will I be able to connect remote server DB in doing it so -

```
<?php

mysql_connect("http://edlabs.in/connect:22","connect","");
mysql_select_db("connect");

for($i=0; $i<=1; $i++){

    $fid_cck = array(mysql_query("SELECT field_upload_doc_fid FROM content_field_upload_doc WHERE field_upload_doc_list > 0"));
    $fid_core = array(mysql_query("SELECT fid FROM upload"));

    foreach($fid_cck as $fid_cck_value){

        foreach($fid_core as $fid_core_value)
        {
            if($fid_cck_value != $fid_core_value){

                $file_name = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM files WHERE fid = $fid_cck");
                $nid_cck = mysql_query("SELECT nid FROM field_upload_doc_fid WHERE fid = $fid_cck");
                $vid_cck = mysql_query("SELECT vid FROM field_upload_doc_fid WHERE fid = $fid_cck");

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload VALUES('$fid_cck', '$nid_cck', '$vid_cck', '$file_name', 1, 0)");

                $filepath = array(mysql_query("SELECT filepath FROM files WHERE fid = $fid_cck"));

                $new_filepath = str_replace("/background_docs", "", $filepath);

                mysql_query("UPDATE files SET filepath=$new_filepath WHERE fid = $fid_cck");

            }
        }
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: *"Because I am not very good at PHP or MySQL I am seeking some help from you guys.."* -- Get a tutor to get your professional work done. Talk to your team leader that you need more training to solve your job. It's important that you make that clear in your context of work, not here.

Comment: I will do care about it..

Thanks :)

Comment: It is fixed for now...I have done that :)

Comment: Cool to read you already solved it! Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it (yes, that works) - this is how this site works and will mark your question as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by following these steps-

1. Created a DB with the same name as my portal at my local phpmyadmin.
2. Exported three table named content_field_upload_doc, files & upload from DB of my portal.
3. Wrote a custom PHP code with some MySQL query to make query and find DIFF of those files which are in content_field_upload_doc but not in upload table & picked the name of that from table files.(I am giving the code below).
4. Ran the code on my wamp and echoed the INSERT query.
5. Copied all the query & executed that with SQL on my phpmyadmin at portal DB.
6. Copied all the files from previous used folder inside public folder & pasted that to default public folder.
7. Removed the CCK field from content type...and it's DONE..!

   `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());`


   }
   else{

   ```
   mysql_select_db("connect");

   $rs_fudl = mysql_query("SELECT vid, nid, field_upload_doc_fid FROM content_field_upload_doc WHERE field_upload_doc_list > '0'");
   while($rs_fudl_row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_fudl))
   {

       $fid_fudl = $rs_fudl_row['field_upload_doc_fid'];

       $rs_file = mysql_query("SELECT filename,filepath FROM files WHERE fid = '$fid_fudl'");

       //echo mysql_num_rows($rs_file)."<br />";

       while($rs_file_row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_file)){

               $rs_upload = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload where fid='".$fid_fudl."'");

               if ( mysql_num_rows($rs_upload) == 0) {

               /*  $new_filepath = str_replace("/background_docs", "", $rs_file_row['filepath']);

                   $filepath = $new_filepath;
               */
                   $filename = $rs_file_row['filename'];
                   $vid_fudl = $rs_fudl_row['vid'];
                   echo "<br />";

                   $nid_fudl = $rs_fudl_row['nid'];
                   echo "<br />";

                   echo "INSERT INTO upload VALUES ('$fid_fudl','$nid_fudl', '$vid_fudl', '$filename','1', '0');" ;
                   echo "<br />";
               //  echo "UPDATE files SET filepath= '$filepath' WHERE fid = '$fid_fudl';";     

               }
       }
   }
   mysql_close($con);
   ```

   }

   ?>